# gnuplot: plotting multiple functions with different ranges

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the inverse of y=xe^x, with dashed lines leading to the point (-exp(-1), -1)

```
set parametric

set arrow 1 from -4,0 to 4,0 nohead
set arrow 2 from 0,-4 to 0,4 nohead

set trange[-4:4]
set xrange[-4:4]
set yrange[-4:4]

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

plot [-4:4] t*exp(t), t lt rgb "black" ,  -exp(-1),t lt rgb "black", t, -1 lt rgb "black"
```

I would like to restrict the vertical line to running from y=-1 to y=0, and the horizontal line from x=-exp(-1) to x=0. How can this be done?

Also, is there an easier way to set the line colour for all plots, rather than specifying it for each one?

[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IztBH.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you draw arrows?  Anyway, you can restrict the domain of a function defining it piecewise through the ternary operator `? :`.  Tip: you can add xy axes with `set zeroaxis` `;-)`

Comment: @user2869037: "dashed lines leading to the point ..." -- where do such lines start?

Comment: @giordano Is it possible to draw dashed arrows? If so, how?

Comment: @user2869037 it depends on the terminal you are using, but in general you can set it with `linetype` option to `set arrow` just like you'd do for a `plot` command.

Comment: I'm afraid this has nothing to do with TeX and friends, while being a good question nonetheless. Maybe [so] is better?

Comment: @julesjanker, since you also did a post on Stackoverflow with the same question. The question there has been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314349/gnuplot-plotting-multiple-functions-with-different-ranges